# Can't build AC-3 Surround Plugin for alsa in 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa

Upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04, I've lost the AC3 Surround feature through optical (IEC958).

I've tried to build it again according to the instructions described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio), but I'm stuck at the install section because the files `libasound_module_pcm_a52.la` and `libasound_module_pcm_a52.so` are missing. What to do if I want to have 5.1 surround sound with my sound system? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've finally solved it. Turns out that you have to put the `a52.conf` to a different path: `/etc/alsa/conf.d` instead of `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.d/`